# I want to creating Network without internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, bridging

I want to Create a network between 3 of our house, which are not close. i want to achieve that without internet connection. so that i will be able to transfer files without internet. recommend any software or device that will aide me in achieving it.

Comment: How close is "not close"?

Comment: Define "not close". Also, why don't you want to use the internet?

Comment: The most obvious solution is to apply for permission to lay ground cables. Which will probably take a few months. Then dig up the sidewalk and lay fibre cables.

Comment: not close as in 100km away. @Zaheylu

Comment: 100km away from each other. i don't want to use the internet because i will be transferring large files which will consume data and i can't pay for that. so i want to use my ISP or my network provider to achieve that but without needing internet connection. @user2313067

Comment: @Hennes That will be very expensive for 100 km ... ;)

Comment: Aye. But you need to use someones cables to transfer that data. Either those from a ISP (aka use the Internet), or your own cables, or rent dedicated cables from your ISP.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly tell us whats the distance between these three houses.
There are a number of options:

- Set up a fiber link between the houses as fiber goes way beyond the 100m limit of copper cables

  Use mesh devices between these houses equiped with strong omni directional antennas e.g. [Mesh Potatoes][1], I personally used these to create a community network with 2nodes that covered 1.2KM but conditions like heights must be considered

  Use Nanostations and create some sort of directional link between the houses

It would also be a good idea to let us know what equipment you currently possess or what your budget is like

Comment: Actually its VISP i want to achieve. because i can't pay for infrastructure and the rest. i read something about wireless penetration whereby the software is able to communicate through the ISP and send data. @Manny264

Comment: I see,im also trying to set up the same with the mesh potato devices. so u deploy these mesh devices and define a gateway i.e. one device that is the default gateway connected2the net and all these will connect via this one. my only problem ryt now is handling billing/authentication via WPA2 enterprise / RADIUS @KingAmada

Comment: which device did you use? and what is the distance that you were able to cover, i mean the radius of your mesh network? and will it cover urban city with mountains, trees, buildings? i will have money for that kind of project. money is not an issue. @Manny264

Comment: I used mesh potato 2s with omni directional antennas. so far the only places I have connected were 1.5KM apart but Ive got some directional antennas with which I will try setting up a 10KM link. use the program radio mobile to account for mountains etc,but u need height when setting up the nodes

Answer (score 0):

100km is to much for any kind of simple local solution. You will either need to:

1. Lay cables (horribly expensive and permissions might be hard to get).
2. Or use wireless (Not home routers or [illegally] boosted SoHo devices, but proper carrier graded devices. Probably on high towers and with their own problems and costs.
3. **Or use exiting cables**.

The last if often used to connect to the Internet, but you can just rent a virtual circuit and leave it unconnected to the Internet.  Your ISP (or whoever rents you this) will still charge for it and is likely to charge more then you pay for a simple  Internet connection.

This means that if you have limited funds:

- Use a regular Internet connection (e.g. uncapped 100mbit/100mbiot fibre, which is about $80 per month).
- Or use a regular connection but build tunnels (same effect as above, but you cut off the Internet part)
- Or rent a virtual circuit (which is usually more expensive but comes with a much better SLA)
- Or build something wireless. E.g. packet radio. Which is **not** fast.

Comment: I like this one "Or use a regular connection but build tunnels (same effect as above, but you cut off the Internet part)" how will i achieve that? @Hennes

Comment: Simply do not add a default route to 0.0.0.0. Just add routes to the known networks.

Comment: Explanation: see [http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)